# Creating sequential numbers in the auto table jspdf column VusJs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, jspdf-autotable

[image]

```
    columns: [
      {
        header: 'No',
        dataKey: 'Index',
      },
      { header: 'No Registrasi', dataKey: 'no_register' },
      { header: 'Kode Partai', dataKey: 'kode_partai' },
      { header: 'Sumber', dataKey: 'kode_partai' },
      { header: 'Tanggal Panen', dataKey: 'tanggal_panen' },
      { header: 'Tanggal Terima', dataKey: 'tanggal_penerima' },
    
    ],
```

```
{
    "success": true,
    "message": "Data ditemukan",
    "data": [
        {
            "id": 15,
            "user_id": 3,
            "no_register": "KREO",
            "kode_partai": "00PPPP",
            "legal_source": "Terdaftar",
            "jenis_sbw_kotor": "9000",
            "tanggal_panen": "2022-02-10",
            "tanggal_penerima": "2022-02-16",
            "alamat": "jl kandir",
            "no_kendaraan": "K 8992993 KW",
            "jumlah_sbw_kotor": "9000",
            "jumlah_pcs": "9000",
            "jumlah_box": "90999",
            "kadar_air": "9000",
            "warna": "Cream",
            "kondisi": "ok",
            "status": "Adding",
            "harga_kulak": "900000000",
            "created_at": "2022-02-24T05:48:07.000000Z",
            "updated_at": "2022-02-24T05:48:07.000000Z"
        },
        {
            "id": 16,
            "user_id": 3,
            "no_register": "KREO",
            "kode_partai": "00PPPP",
            "legal_source": "Terdaftar",
            "jenis_sbw_kotor": "9000",
            "tanggal_panen": "2022-02-10",
            "tanggal_penerima": "2022-02-16",
            "alamat": "jl kandir",
            "no_kendaraan": "K 8992993 KW",
            "jumlah_sbw_kotor": "9000",
            "jumlah_pcs": "9000",
            "jumlah_box": "90999",
            "kadar_air": "9000",
            "warna": "Cream",
            "kondisi": "ok",
            "status": "Adding",
            "harga_kulak": "900000000",
            "created_at": "2022-02-24T05:48:07.000000Z",
            "updated_at": "2022-02-24T05:48:07.000000Z"
        }
    ]
}
```

I've tried to use index + 1, but it doesn't work. I want my dataKey to be filled with sequential numbers according to the number of Arrays I get from the api service's response. in what other way so that I can enter the serial number in the 'NO' column.I use Vuejs

Comment: Could you add some example data of your servers response? Maybe it's the easiest to just add a new column to the data (only in the frontend).

Comment: I have added it above bro @jkoch

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add a index field to your data with the map function.

```js
const dataWithIndex = serverResponse.data.map((d,i) => ({...d,Index:i+1}));
```

Comment: { header: 'No', dataKey: 'dataWithIndex' }, or   { header: 'No', dataKey: dataWithIndex } not work. this method use

Comment: Use `{header: 'No', dataKey: 'Index'}` like in your question.

Comment: https://prnt.sc/0W1-0LPLeqOQ this code @jkoch

Comment: no work use https://prnt.sc/0W1-0LPLeqOQ

Comment: Change `body: this.dataListAdding.data` to `body: dataWithIndex`